# Solving an equation including a sum; How to find the right sum index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, equation

I try to find the index of a sum that solves an equation. I have a vector holding different values and i want to find the element in that vector up to which all the elements equal a certain value. How can i do that?

I already  tried the solve function, but that does not work.

Here is what i tried:

```
A = [120 90 87 75 43 41 33 29 21]
syms x
eqn = sum(A(1,1:x)) == 297
solx = solve(eqn,x)
```

The solution should be x = 3 (120 + 90 + 87 = 297) but i get an error.

I'm pretty new to matlab and it would be really great if someone could help :)

Comment: Try `cumsum(A)`, see if you like the result! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would solve your problem:

```
 A = [120 90 87 75 43 41 33 29 21];
 eqn = cumsum(A) == 297;
 solx = find(eqn)
```

Hope it helped!